# How can I use Java libraries' methods in MATLAB?

Tags: java, matlab, java-8

I am using MATLAB R2016a. I already have set `MATLAB_JAVA`, and `JAVA_PATH` environment variable. Also, if I try and run Java in Matlab, is shows something like this

[image: Error]

This is the first Simple hello world program,

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String s[]){
   System.out.println("Hello World, I am Here");
    }
 }
```

After compiling this with **javac** from cmd, I used following to call it from Matlab

```
obj = Test
javaMethod('main',obj,'')
```

It threw the output:

```
Hello World, I am Here
```

This is the second program I wrote

```
import java.io.*;
class Addition{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
int a,b,c;
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter the two numbers to add:");
a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
b=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
c = a+b;
System.out.println("\nOkay, Sum of two numbers are:"+ c);
}
}
```

After compiling when I wrote this in Matlab

```
objtt = Addition
```

It gave error, as shown in the figure

```
No constructor 'Addition' with matching signature found.
```

PS: To set up Java Environment in Matlab, I used information from [here](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/130359-how-do-i-change-the-java-virtual-machine-jvm-that-matlab-is-using-on-windows). 
Please let me know if missed any steps that is causing the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have to use the fully qualified name to access Java methods

Comment: So the parameters or attributes for those methods should be in format of java or matlab?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You need to use the fully qualified name (i.e. `com.yourthing.Addition`

Comment: This is what I have done so far.
I wrote a simple hello world program(Hello.java), compiled it via the cmd in windows(which generated the class file), and then from the Matlab command window I just called Hello (like javaMethod('main',obj,'')). It worked like a charm. 
But then I wrote another program to add 2 numbers, compiled in cmd, and again tried calling it through Matlab Command window, and this is when it showed the error.

Comment: I would suggest adding that information to your question, along with the code for the two Java programs, the matlab commands you used to call them, and the error message you received.